# kernel timer function error

Tags: linux, timer, kernel, tizen

I try to modify the tizen kernel.
I am testing each line. So, I find mod_timer is kernel error
What's the problem???

code is

```
  void timer_add(void){
      struct timer_list timer; 
      setup_timer(&timer, kill_callback, 0); 
      mod_timer(&timer, jiffies + msecs_to_jiffies(3000));
  }

 void kill_callback(unsigned long data)
{
    sys_kill(current->pid, SIGKILL);
    return ;
}
```

[   19.029281] Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual addre

Comment: dump file is 

     c002de24:       e593200c        ldr     r2, [r3, #12]
     c002de28:       e3120001        tst     r2, #1
     c002de2c:       1a000004        bne     c002de44 <get_next_timer_interrupt+0x144>
     c002de30:       e5932008        ldr     r2, [r3, #8]

Comment: Please tell us about which tizen profile or kernel sources ?

Answer (score 1):

Your function timer_add declares local variable timer, which goes out of scope when the function returns. But you pass it as an argument to function setup_timer, where it is used to set up your call back function.

When the call back function is executed at a later time, it references your variable timer, which does not exist any more.

You either have to declare your variable timer as a static variable or use a global variable.